# std::hash redefinition error in STL after upgrade to Xcode13

Tags: xcode, clang, avfoundation, xcode13

Don't see any reason to have such error. What it can be?
Here the compiler call with includes and object files name omitted

```
> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -x objective-c++ -target arm64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=c++20 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/dcow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
> -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/dcow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
> -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -mdynamic-no-pic -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DDEBUG\=1 -DGPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS\=1 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DWK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY\=0 -DDEBUG\=1 -DPB_FIELD_32BIT\=1 -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS\=1 -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk
> -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path
```

It's utility.h file from iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk included in AVFoundation.h
[image: utility.h error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Most likely you are including some other code that contains evil defines, like `#define bool char`.

Comment: @code I wish it is something like such define. But code is compilable under Xcode12.5, the compiler is only difference (I believe)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.